# how can I enter text in a var textarray from other part of html?

Tags: javascript, html, random

I'd like to show random pieces of text, so I stumbled upon this code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var textarray = [
       "hi",
       "hello there",
       "how r u",
       "where r u"
    ];

    function RndText() {
       var rannum= Math.floor(Math.random()*textarray.length);
       document.getElementById('ShowText').innerHTML=textarray[rannum];
    }

    onload = function() { RndText(); }

</script>
</head>
<body>
     <div id="ShowText"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

However, what I need to do is to have dynamic inputs in my textarray, let's say from the contents of an unordered list:

```
 <div id"textPool">
    <ul>
        <li>Hi</li>
        <li>hello</li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

How is it possible?

Appreciate any help...

Comment: Use `getElementById()` to find the DIV, `getElementsByTagName()` to find all the LI elements inside it, loop over them and add the `.innerHTML` to your array.

Comment: how do you want the array to be created / filled? your question isn't clear at all.

Comment: panos, Check my answer with verified result. Given a **fiddle** too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go.

```
function randomText() {
    var textPool = document.getElementById("textPool");
    var listItems = textPool.getElementsByTagName("li");
    var texts = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++ ) {
        texts.push(listItems[i].innerText);
    }

    var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*listItems.length);
    document.getElementById('ShowText').innerHTML = texts[random];
}

window.onload = randomText;
```

[Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Tc9F7/)

Comment: I think, this does the trick. Thank you very much! Saved my ... well you know!

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
var textArray = document.getElementById('somelistid').getElementsByTagName('li')
```

This would give you an array. Then you can set the text like this with the array.

```
document.getElementById('ShowText').innerHTML=textarray[rannum].innerHTML;
```

You Should however really start using jQuery.

```
var textArray = ('#somelistid').find('li');
```

when you later set it you would use the .text() method instead of the innerHTML. This should run faster.

I actually think you should start looking at something like angularJS.

Here is some simple examples http://www.tomharris.net/test/angularJS

And great training here
http://angularjs.org/

Answer (score 0):

I played around with your question, but I don't know if the result fits with what you want. Take a look at this demo and let me know.

- `init`: fills `textarray` based on the acutal HTML list then calls `shuffle`.
- `addInput`: adds a new item to `textarray` then calls `showList`.
- `showList`: outputs the content of `textarray`.
- `shuffle`: outputs one if the items randomly.

```js
var textarray = [],
    input, list, result;

function init() {
    var items;
    input = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
    list = document.getElementById('list');
    result = document.getElementById('result');
    items = list.getElementsByTagName('li');
    items = Array.prototype.slice.call(items, 0, items.length);
    while (items.length) {
        textarray.push(items.shift().innerHTML);
    }
    shuffle();
}
 
function addInput() {
    if (input.value) {
        textarray.push(input.value);
        input.value = '';
        showList();
    }
}
 
function showList() {
    list.innerHTML = 'textarray :';
    list.innerHTML += '<ul><li>' + textarray.join('</li><li>') + '</li></ul>';
}
 
function shuffle() {
    var rannum = Math.floor(Math.random() * textarray.length);
    result.innerHTML = textarray[rannum];
}

onload = init;
```

```css
*{font-family:Consolas}
.panel{border:1px solid #ccc;padding:10px;margin-bottom:10px}
```

```html
<div class="panel">
    <button onclick="shuffle()">Shuffle</button>
    <span>: "<span id="result"></span>"</span>
</div>
<div class="panel">
    <input type="text" />
    <button onclick="addInput()">Add</button>
</div>
<div class="panel" id="list">
    textarray :
    <ul>
        <li>hello</li>
        <li>world</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code(with a minute change in `textarray` and `RndText()` function):

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var textarray = [];

    function RndText() {
        for(var i=0; i<document.getElementById('textPool').getElementsByTagName('li').length; i++)
            textarray.push(document.getElementById('textPool').getElementsByTagName('li')[i].innerHTML);
        var rannum= Math.floor(Math.random()*textarray.length);
        document.getElementById('ShowText').innerHTML=textarray[rannum];
    }

    onload = function() { RndText(); }

</script>
</head>
<body>
     <div id="ShowText"></div>
     <ul id="textPool">
        <li>hi
        <li>hello there
        <li>how r u
        <li>where r u
     </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is the **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NTkWc/)**

Answer (score -1):

If you are open to using jQuery then following will work :

```
document.getElementById('ShowText').innerHTML=$('#textPool li:eq('+rannum+')').text();
```